# Put 2 jquery functions in 1 function

Tags: jquery, function

I have two functions. How can i make from this 2 jquery effects / functions: 1 jquery code.

```
// Function 1. For hover over the .landkaart
var hover = false;

$(".landkaart > ul > li > a").hover(function () {
    if ( hover == true ) {
        $(this).closest("li").removeClass('open');
        hover = false;
    }  else {
        $(".landkaart ul li .pijl").hide();

        $(this).closest("li").addClass('open');

        console.log(this);

        $(".pijl").show();
        hover = true;
    }
});
```

---

```
// Interval for the .landkaart
var listitem = $(".landkaart > ul > li"),
    len = listitem.length,
    index = 0;

$(".landkaart > ul > li:first").addClass('open');

setInterval(function () {
    $(".landkaart > ul > li").removeClass('open');    
    if ( (index + 1) >= len ) {
        index = 0;
        $(".landkaart > ul > li:first").addClass('open');
    } else {
        listitem.eq(index).next().addClass('open');
    }
    index++;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Describe what's its purpose. Bet this could be quite smaller

Comment: If you pass only one callback function to the hover() method, that callback function will be used for both moseenter and mouseleave events. Do you want that?

Comment: In the setInterval, just use `listitem` instead of `$(".landkaart > ul > li")`, also use `listitem.first()` instead of `$(".landkaart > ul > li:first")`

Comment: yeah. But how can i make this smaller?

Comment: Why are you doing this? `$(".pijl").hide().show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, so I tried to optimize your code.

If you do something more complex in the hover function, you can use `trigger()` inside the timer to call the hover function (see commented out lines), but as it stands there really isn't a need to "combine" the functions like you are asking ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ffqBR/)):

CSS

```
.pijl { display: none; }
.open a { color: #f00; }
.open .pijl { display: inline-block; }
```

Script

```
// Interval for the .landkaart
var listitem = $(".landkaart li"),
    len = listitem.length,
    index = 0,
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        index = (index + 1) % len;
        // use trigger to simulate a mouseenter and activate the hover event
        // listitem.eq(index).trigger('mouseenter');            
        // but it might be better to just do this:
        listitem.removeClass('open').eq(index).addClass('open');
    }, 5000);

listitem
    .hover(function() {
        listitem.removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass("open");
    })
    .eq(0).addClass('open');
```